# Uncaught ReferenceError: Vue is not defined in .vue file

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js

Hi so I'm new to vue and I have installed vue-cli globally and wonder why I get this Error :

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Vue is not defined
at eval (Hello.vue?13ca:73)
at Object.<anonymous> (main.js:1061)
at __webpack_require__ (main.js:679)
at fn (main.js:89)
at eval (Hello.vue?549c:1)
at Object.<anonymous> (main.js:1049)
at __webpack_require__ (main.js:679)
at fn (main.js:89)
at eval (index.js?fc04:1)
at Object.<anonymous> (main.js:1035)
```

my main.js looks like this:

```
import 'bootstrap';
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App';
import router from './router';


Vue.config.productionTip = false;

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: {
    App,
  },
});
```

Since index.js is also referenced I also post the code for it :

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Router from 'vue-router';
import Hello from '../components/Hello';


Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Hello',
      component: Hello,
    },
  ],
});
```

The error is because of this part in the Hello.vue file, when I delete this everything seems ok :

```
<script>

  var nav = new Vue({  
  el: '#loginButtons',
  methods: {
    open: function(which, e) {
      // Prevents clicking the link from doing anything
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: `Hello.vue` shouldn't have anything like `new Vue` in it. It's a component. See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html for examples.

Comment: Ok thank you that was a stupid mistake...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<script>` tags of single file components have to `export` the object you'd normally pass to the `new Vue()` constructor. You also don't need the `el` property because Vue will use the `<template>` as the root element.

```
<script>
export {
  methods: {
    open: function(which, e) {
      // Prevents clicking the link from doing anything
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  }
};
</script>
```